# Why does this duplicate or overwrite the contents of the list?

Tags: arrays, perl, list, hash, push

I am new to Perl and I can't quite get what's wrong with my code. I believe I used the syntax properly but I suspect the problem might be with this line:

```
push @students, \%information;
```

What i want is for the list of students to contain hashes of the student's information. What i expect is that after every addition of student, another hash of the student's information is created and gets linked to the latest index of the list. What happens though is that if i entered student data simultaneously, the latest overwrites the previous so when you print it, you'll see the duplicate of the latest inputted information in the previous list entry. If I inputted 1 student and viewed it right away upon addition, then inputted another student, the latest student overwrites the previous student. Can someone shed light to this? Thank you!

Here is my code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $userchoice = 0;
my $i;
my @students    = ();    #empty array
my %information = ();

while ( $userchoice != 4 ) {
    print "------------------------------\n";
    print "Welcome! What would you like to do?\n";
    print "[0]Create Student Record\n";
    print "[1]Edit Student Record\n";
    print "[2]View Student Record\n";
    print "[3]Delete Student Record\n";
    print "[4]Exit\n";
    print "Your Choice : ";
    $userchoice = <STDIN>;
    chomp($userchoice);

    if ( $userchoice == 0 ) {
        print "-----------\n";
        print "CREATE STUDENT RECORD.\n";
        if ( $#students <= 9 ) {
            print "Name : ";
            $information{"name"} = <STDIN>;
            chomp( $information{"name"} );
            push @students, \%information;
        }
        print "Student Record Full. " if ( $#students >= 10 );
    }

    if ( $userchoice == 2 ) {
        print "\nVIEW STUDENTS.\n";
        print "[0]View One Student\n";
        print "[1]View All Students\n";
        print "[2]Back to Main Menu\n";
        print "Your Choice : ";
        $userchoice = <STDIN>;
        if ( $userchoice == 1 ) {
            print "VIEW ALL STUDENTS.\n";

            print "STUDENT 1---------------\n";
            print "Name : ", $students[0]->{"name"}, " \n";
            print "STUDENT 2---------------\n";
            print "Name : ", $students[1]->{"name"}, " \n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use a reference to a new hash each time, rather than trying to reference the same hash each time.  The simplest way to do that is to define `%information` inside the loop body.

Comment: Got it fixed! Thanks to Jonathan. It really was getting duplicated because the list sorts of references the same hash... Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in a comment:

> You need to use a reference to a new hash each time, rather than trying to reference the same hash each time. The simplest way to do that is to define `%information` inside the loop body.

Your code is currently:

```
my %information = ();

while ( $userchoice != 4 ) {
    print "------------------------------\n";
```

It would work correctly (or, at least, this aspect of it would work correctly) if you used:

```
while ( $userchoice != 4 ) {
    my %information = ();
    print "------------------------------\n";
```

Comment: Exactly what I did and it worked fine after that. Thank you for giving more details on it!

Answer (score 4):

This is always pushing a reference to the same hash onto the array `push @students,\%information;`
To illustrate:

```
my %hash = ( index => 0 );
my @list = ();
foreach my $i (1..3) {
    $hash{index} = $i;
    push @list, \%hash;
}

for ( my $i=0; $i<@list; $i++ ) {
    print "item $i - $list[$i] - $list[$i]->{index}\n";
}
```

Notice from the output that the address is the same for each:

```
item 0 - HASH(0x4c8068) - 3
item 1 - HASH(0x4c8068) - 3
item 2 - HASH(0x4c8068) - 3
```

You can fix by either declaring %information inside the loop

```
while($userchoice!=4){
    my %information = ();
```

Or by forcing a new reference when you push:

```
push @students, { %information };
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem arises because you're putting the reference to the same hash in your array for each student:

```
push @students, \%information;
```

One solution to this would be to simply create a new anonymous hash for each record:

```
push @students, { %information };
```

However, I believe that you could also use a lesson in limiting the scope of your variables.

Always use the smallest scope possible when declaring a variable.  This both helps document your code, and also reduces the chance of accidentally misusing a variable like this.

The following is a rewrite of your script to remove all the variables used in a global scope:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @students = ();    #empty array

while (1) {
    print "------------------------------\n";
    print "Welcome! What would you like to do?\n";
    print "[0]Create Student Record\n";
    print "[1]Edit Student Record\n";
    print "[2]View Student Record\n";
    print "[3]Delete Student Record\n";
    print "[4]Exit\n";
    print "Your Choice : ";
    chomp( my $userchoice = <STDIN> );

    last if $userchoice == 4;

    if ( $userchoice == 0 ) {
        print "-----------\n";
        print "CREATE STUDENT RECORD.\n";
        if ( @students <= 10 ) {
            print "Name : ";
            chomp( my $name = <STDIN> );
            push @students, { name => $name };
        }
        print "Student Record Full. " if ( @students > 10 );
    }

    if ( $userchoice == 2 ) {
        print "\nVIEW STUDENTS.\n";
        print "[0]View One Student\n";
        print "[1]View All Students\n";
        print "[2]Back to Main Menu\n";
        print "Your Choice : ";
        chomp( my $userchoice = <STDIN> );
        if ( $userchoice == 1 ) {
            print "VIEW ALL STUDENTS.\n";

            for my $i ( 1 .. @students ) {
                print "STUDENT $i---------------\n";
                print "Name : ", $students[ $i - 1 ]{"name"}, " \n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```